# How to dynamically limit the scroll area in Excel utilizing VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to limit the scroll area of an Excel sheet depending on the chosen dataset.
The amount of data of each set is variable and differs a lot. As a result, a solution as seen below will not work. Is it possible to use something like Cells(n, 30)?

Thanks in advance!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
     ActiveSheet.ScrollArea = "A3:F2000"
End Sub
```

Comment: ActiveSheet.ScrollArea=Cells(n,30).address

Comment: Or  ```ActiveSheet.ScrollArea = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address``` if you want restrict only to used cells.